# Issue with X-Pack installation

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin, xpack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I have installed X-Pack on elasticsearch and start elasticsearch using command bin/elasticsearch .

and i have installed X-Pack on kibana and while starting kibana using bin/kibana ,
i’m getting result as mentioned below and kibana is not working :

```
log   [08:40:56.376] [info][status][plugin:kibana@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [08:40:56.526] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [08:40:56.541] [info][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [08:40:56.582] [warning] You're running Kibana 5.4.0 with some different versions of Elasticsearch. Update Kibana or Elasticsearch to the same version to prevent compatibility issues: v5.4.1 @ 10.1.1.121:9200 (10.1.1.121)
  log   [08:40:56.609] [info][status][plugin:graph@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [08:40:56.629] [info][status][plugin:monitoring@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [08:40:56.636] [warning][reporting] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [08:40:56.645] [info][status][plugin:reporting@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [08:40:56.691] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.4.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Kibana index ready
  log   [08:40:56.702] [info][status][plugin:security@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [08:40:56.703] [warning][security] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [08:40:56.725] [warning][security] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
  log   [08:40:56.814] [info][status][plugin:searchprofiler@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [08:40:56.818] [warning][license][xpack] License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch. [illegal_argument_exception] No endpoint or operation is available at [_xpack] :: {"path":"/_xpack","statusCode":400,"response":"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"No endpoint or operation is available at [_xpack]\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"No endpoint or operation is available at [_xpack]\"},\"status\":400}"}
  log   [08:40:56.821] [error][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.4.0] Status changed from yellow to red - X-Pack plugin is not installed on Elasticsearch cluster
  log   [08:40:56.823] [error][status][plugin:graph@5.4.0] Status changed from yellow to red - X-Pack plugin is not installed on Elasticsearch cluster
  log   [08:40:56.824] [error][status][plugin:reporting@5.4.0] Status changed from yellow to red - X-Pack plugin is not installed on Elasticsearch cluster
  log   [08:40:56.825] [error][status][plugin:security@5.4.0] Status changed from yellow to red - X-Pack plugin is not installed on Elasticsearch cluster
  log   [08:40:56.826] [error][status][plugin:searchprofiler@5.4.0] Status changed from yellow to red - X-Pack plugin is not installed on Elasticsearch cluster
  log   [08:40:56.833] [error][status][plugin:ml@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to red - X-Pack plugin is not installed on Elasticsearch cluster
  log   [08:40:56.865] [info][status][plugin:ml@5.4.0] Status changed from red to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [08:40:56.879] [error][status][plugin:tilemap@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to red - X-Pack plugin is not installed on Elasticsearch cluster
  log   [08:40:56.884] [error][status][plugin:watcher@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to red - X-Pack plugin is not installed on Elasticsearch cluster
  log   [08:40:56.926] [info][status][plugin:console@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [08:40:56.936] [info][status][plugin:ml@5.4.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [08:40:56.945] [info][status][plugin:metrics@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [08:40:57.120] [info][status][plugin:timelion@5.4.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [08:40:57.126] [fatal] Port 5601 is already in use. Another instance of Kibana may be running!
FATAL Port 5601 is already in use. Another instance of Kibana may be running!
```

Answer (score 0):

> Port 5601 is already in use. Another instance of Kibana may be
>   running!

As the error states, you already have something running on port 5601.

If your on on Linux, you can use lsof to identify the process using the port `lsof -i :5601`.

You can then kill the process using the PID in the results.